# How do you take only float values from a row that is a mixture of strings and floats

Tags: sql

Basically what I have is a row of values that has a variety of different things in the row. Currently the values range from numbers to values such as "Not Available", etc.

How would I be able to grab all the float values from the row, while leaving behind all the other values.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Rows contain columns.  If you want specific columns, use `SELECT`.

Comment: The S in SQL stands for _stuctured_. But your data seems to be _unstructured_, which is something that SQL doesn't handle very well.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is lite on details; it's best to provide more context, so that the community can better answer your question.  But, making some assumptions ...

Normally, each column in a table has a data type, so (without knowing anything else about your table) I would say just `SELECT` the columns that have the numeric data that you are after; e.g.

```
SELECT numberColOne, numberColTwo FROM table_of_stuff;
```

But if you are saying that a given column might have a floating-point number *OR* a bit of text (like "Not Available"), then your choices depend heavily on the RDBMS (MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, SQLite, etc) in use.  I imagine you could use a `CASE .. WHEN .. ELSE` construct on each column, testing for numericality and yielding a sentinel value for the strings.  ... But that's kinda what you already have : a mix of numeric and non-numeric data.

So if you are instead looking to transform source data such as this:

```
row 1 : 3.1415926  Not Available  2.1111         6.6667   Not Available
row 2 : 2.71828    1.2222         Not Available  3.33333  4.50
```

into:

```
row 1 : 3.1415926  2.1111  6.6667
row 2 : 2.71828    1.2222  3.33333  4.50
```

then I agree with the comment from @jarlh : SQL is not what you want to use.  In this case, you might use SQL to pull everything from the table into an export file, and then process that file with code (`bash`, `sed`, `perl`, etc.) to remove the string values.  As @jarlh said, SQL is all about *structured* data, and if you want something unstructured, you need to combine tools.

HTH.